# bootstrap header before container

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, structure

I'm sorry for what may seem a dumb question, but I would like to know if I can structure my code like this?

```
<header class="header col-md-12" >
 <div class="header-inner container">
  <!-- contents -->
 </div>
</header>
<div class="container">
 <!-- contents -->
</div>
```

I want to have a header wrap that is from one end of the screen to the other and then an inside header div that behaves as .container, i used the .col, because I read you can't nest containers, so it does behave the way I want it to, but I would like to know if it is a correct/viable way to do it.

[image: Scetch of what I want to do]

Thank you in advance

Comment: Usually `.container` or `.container-fluid` are used as top-level containers within which one or more `.row` is kept.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your example, you should remove the `.col-md-12` class from the `header`.

And make sure that `.header-inner` is not overriding the default `.container` style attributes, otherwise you need to place it inside in `.header-inner` or place the `.header-inner` class inside of `.container`, depending on your needs:

Take a look at this example page: http://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/

I believe, that's what you are looking for.

Find more examples here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/#examples

Comment: Thanks, for the info and sources.